# What does it mean to say two matrices are conjugate?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was asked to find two 2 x 2 matrices over $R$ which have the same characteristic polynomial but which are not conjugate. What does it mean to say two matrices are conjugate in this context?

Comment: It seems to be quite an old piece of terminology. See [here](shorturl.at/mwEK6)

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are conjugate if there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$. In other words, $A$ and $B$ represent the same endomorphism (but in different bases).

Comment: Similar. As for your example, consider $O$ and $\text{Col}(0,e_1)$. Both have characteristic polynomial $p(\lambda)=\lambda^2$ but are not similar. (Why?)

Comment: @nejimban I would call $A,B$ similar matrices if there exists a matrix $P$ such that $B = P^{-1}AP.$  I would call $\bar A$ the conjugate of $A$ if every element of $\bar A$ was the complex conjugate of its corresponding element in $A.$  That doesn't mean my definition is correct in this case.  There should be a definition in whatever book the OP is working from.

Comment: @MatthewPilling What do you mean by matrix  and (0,1)?

Comment: @You1234 $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ respectively, I'd imagine.

Comment: @DougM I think the one I gave is still more likely and comes from the [general definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class) in group theory. But I agree 'similar' is more common in linear algebra (I suppose because of the confusion with the complex operation you mentioned).

Comment: @nejimban I think the problem is that the conjugate transpose is pretty common in linear algebra, and this is indeed the complex conjugates of the elements, transposed.